# Calculating cyclic extensions of a group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-extensions

I am having trouble understanding how to calculate all possible cyclic extensions of a group. 
I have been following the text 'A Course In Group Theory' by John F. Humphreys, and also referring to some notes [Here](https://www.math.wisc.edu/~boston/notes4.pdf) by Martin Isaacs.

1. In the notes linked to above, it says that one of the conditions on
   $ \sigma \in Aut(N)$ is that $ \sigma ^{m}$ is the inner
   automorphism of $ N $ induced by $ a $ . Am I correct in thinking
   this means that $\sigma ^{m} $ is the same as conjugating by $a$ ?
2. If I had a group $G$ with a subgroup $N$ with index $p$ (a prime) , and I wanted to know how many such groups  $G$ exist, would
   calculating all the extensions of $N$ by the cyclic group of order
   $p$ answer this question?
3. I am confused about the role of the $a\in N$. To count the number of extensions, would I have to go through each of the $|N|$
   possible choices of $a$, and for each $a$ count the number of
   automorphisms $\sigma \in Aut(N)$ that obey the conditions that:
   $a^{\sigma}=a$ and  $ \sigma ^{m}$ is the inner automorphism of $ N
       $ induced by $ a $
4. Could somebody explain the steps I should go through to find all cyclic extensions of a group $N$ by some cyclic group $H$ ,  and if
   possible recommend where I can find some worked examples.

Thank you

Comment: The answer to 1 is yes. As for 2, they are closely related questions, but not identical. Inequivalent extensions can be isomorphic as groups. Also you could have a group isomorphism that did not map your $N$ in the first extension to your $N$ in the second one.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am not sure I completely follow your last sentence. If I know that all groups with some property X must have a subgroup N ( where N is known) of index p, is there a way for me to use the theory of extensions to construct all possible groups G, or st least to bound them? Thank you.

Comment: Using the theory of extensions, you will construct all possible extensions of $\mathbb{Z}/p$ by $N$. In particular, any isomorphism class of group with property $X$ arise this way. However, what Derek Holt says is that with those extensions, you are far from the classification of isomorphism classes (e.g. different extensions can be weakly equivalent).

Comment: For 3. No, you have to go through all possible choices of group morphism from $\mathbb{Z}/p$ to $Out(N):=Aut(N)/Int(N)$. For 4.  maybe you should try $p=2$ and $N=\mathbb{Z}/4$ and $\mathbb{Z}/2\times \mathbb{Z}/2$. Doing this you will recover all groups of order $8$. Alejandro Adem and Milgram's "cohomology of finite groups" contains (IMHO) good material to understand group extensions and many examples...

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I think I am closer to understanding what you mean. Is the following correct: If I find all the extension of $N$ by the cyclic group $C_{p}$ then I find all possible groups of order $p|n|$ containing a subgroup isomorphic to $N$. However the problem is that of these groups that I find, some of them may be isomorphic even if they arise from different extensions.

Comment: Yes that is correct!